# Making a sound when it notifies over a websocket

Tags: reactjs, audio, websocket, notifications, policy

Hello my problem is that i can't make a sound when my browser notifies right after reloading the page.
According to policies and to my understanding, I need to click somewhere in the DOM first. Then it starts making sound on notifications.

Here is my code

```
  const audioPlayer = useRef(null);

  function playAudio() {
    audioPlayer.current.play();
  }

  const { sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(socketUrl);
  const [api, contextHolder] = notification.useNotification();
  const openNotification = (placement) => {
    playAudio();
    api.info({
      message: `Notification ${placement}`,
      description:
        'This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification.',
      placement,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastMessage !== null) {
      openNotification("bottomRight");
    }
  }, [lastMessage]);
```

And jsx part of my code

```
      {contextHolder}
      <audio ref={audioPlayer} src={NotificationSound} autoPlay />
```

Actually it all works fine just with one exception. And I mentioned that exception at the beginning of my question.

So how can I solve this problem?
I don't want to click on document in order to hear the sound of notification.

The error that I have encountered with when notification comes right after reloading the page is this

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

I don't get this error after I click somewhere on the page.

Well I have no about how to solve this problem.
So help me please!